# Custom theme de Wordpress no muestra elementos del head

Tags: bootstrap, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theme

Estoy desarrollando un tema de wordpress con bootstrap para un cliente.

El sitio funciona bien pero al ajustarlo a wordpress, varios elementos del archivo head no aparecen como el metatag de viewport y el navbar.

Además, incluye este header con el título y descripción del sitio en lugar de mi barra de navegación.

```
<div id="header" role="banner">
<div id="headerimg">
    <h1><a href="http://localhost:8888/mibi-wp/"></a></h1>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

---

**NOTA:** ya incluí `wp_head()` antes del cierre de la etiqueta `</head>` y llamé al archivo mediante `get_header()`.
¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo solucionarlo?